# show year + auto increment as column register

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, zerofill

i have column register on table jadwal:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'jadwal' ('register' int(5) zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY ('register')
```

i want to show register combine, this year + auto_increment 
like:

```
1800001
1800002
1800003
```

and reset become
1900001 when year is 2019

i try to add Y on mysql like CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jadwal ( register int(5) Y zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, but not working

please help the source code and many thanks

Comment: What you have tried until now?

Comment: i try to add Y on mysql like CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jadwal` (
  `register` int(5) Y zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, but not working,

Comment: Please add it to the question using the edit function, not as comment

Comment: As my understanding of your question, it is not possible

Comment: ok, thank you for the instructions

Comment: is there another alternative so I can display 1800001?

Comment: Not as i know. You can not restart an Auto_increment yearly

Comment: how about just display 1800001, without reset yearlly?

Comment: Than you can concat it in the selct

Comment: You can also use Virtual Fields. Then you can CONCAT everything. Read the Manual. There is a litte Difference between MySQL and MariaDB to create a FIELD

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

- Use `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`
- Insert a bogus entry at midnight of Jan. 1 each year.  Use the value 1900001 for the beginning of 2019.

(Or you could use `1900000` and delete it *after* another entry has been made.)

The alternative is a bit messier -- It would involve a Trigger that looks at `YEAR(CURDATE())` to see if the 'next' id needs to be bumped up to the start of the next year.